# Non-interactive authentication in Azure App Service with authentication enabled

Tags: authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

We have an App Service hosting a Web API with the following authentication settings (in the Azure portal under "Settings" - "Authentication"):

- App service authentication: `Enabled`
- Restrict access: `Require authentication`
- Unauthenticated requests: `Return HTTP 302 Found (Redirect to identity provider)`
- Redirect to: `Microsoft`
- Token store: `Enabled`

Opening the Swagger page redirects to a login popup which after logging in sets a cookie with the name `AppServiceAuthSession`, and everything works.

But how do I call the Web API *non-interactively*? I have acquired a bearer token for a Managed Identity non-interactively, but using it in the authorization header results in `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` Is it necessary to set the `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie (and if yes, how do I get its value)?

Comment: Change the `stdoutLogEnabled` value to true and run the application. Log file will be created with the detailed error in the `C:\home\LogFiles> folder`.You will find the `Web.config` file in the deployed Azure App service.

Comment: The detailed errors are not helpful -  it basically just says Unauthorized. The question really is: do I need to set the cookie `AppServiceAuthSession` in a non-interactive context and, if yes, how do I get it?

Comment: Could you please share your code.

Comment: The code is not relevant here, it's the same using e.g. Postman. Perhaps a bit more background: The ASP.NET controllers are protected using `[Authorize]`. Before the authentication settings were enabled, the controller methods could be called by acquiring the access token (e.g. using Postman) and adding it to the header. Now, with authentication setting enabled, the access token doesn't seem to be sufficient anymore.